Make and copy a folder into different folders using cp
I have a simple question, I wanted to copy a particular folder and make several copies of it.
I used the following command:
cp -r 5_ {6..10}_

And I get the following message:
cp: target '10_' is not a directory
The following command works and does the job as I wanted.
for i in {6..10}; do cp -r 5_ ${i}_; done

However I was wondering why the first command wouldnt work? Meanwhile commands with mkdir and rm all work like:
mkdir {6..10}_

rm -rf {6..10}_

If someone can shed a bit of light it would be very helpful.

cp has a man page which clarifies this:

Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

Therefore, you cannot copy to multiple destinations with the same cp. It's just not supported by design.
